# Xamarin - Multi-targetting - "'System.ValueTuple`2' is declared in multiple referenced"

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, c#-7.0, multitargeting

As soon as I try to compile code that use C# 7 tuples with multi targets (`netstandard2.0` and `xamarin.iOS`) I got the following error:

> Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is declared in multiple
>   referenced assemblies

Comment: Those targets do not need the ValueTuple NuGet, so maybe remove that?

Comment: I haven't added ValueTuple as a nuget package nowhere. However, I do use it so its coming from somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know which assemblies the conflict occurred in.
However, I realized I had not myself added the `ValueTuple` nuget package so I explicitly did and the error went away.

Answer (score 10):

It might've been added automatically as a reference from another package. Just remove that NuGet package to resolve the conflict.

`uninstall-package System.ValueTuple` is the command for the package manager console.

Comment: That's the opposite: I had to add the nuget package.